# Changing date format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, date-conversion

i have dates taht are saved in the database in the format of YYYY-mm-dd (ex. 2013-01-31). In some areas I need to display the date as MMM dd, YYYY (ex. Jan 31, 2013). Can anyone help me in this converting.

I am using php and a mysql database. So far I have this to separate the date values, but dont know how to change them to what I want:

```
list($BYear, $BMonth, $BDay) = explode('-', $DateOfBirth);
$CYear = date('Y');
$CMonth = date('m');
$CDay = date('d');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of database? How are you displaying them? Is this a web application? Desktop application with GUI? Command line? What language?

Comment: sorry - using php and mysql

Comment: Okay, please update your question to be more specific.  And please tell us what you've already tried.  Don't ask others to do your work for you: try something, watch it fail, figure out why, repeat until it works.  Ask questions _along_the_way_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
select date_format(field, '%M %d, %Y') from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want display then you can use this.

```
<?php echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($DateOfBirth)); ?>
```

---

Comment: thanks a bunch works like a charm - i am completing someone elses work and have very little experience in php.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
select convert(varchar(20),@YOUR_DATE,107)
```